# Juptyer Notebooks Authentication

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

I'm very new to Jupyter notebooks and recently setup a dev instance with a basic password for external access. While this works fine, I need to tie it into LDAP or PAM authentication on my RHEL server.

As I started reading about this, it appears JupyterHub is the way to go with but I'm running into some issues with that setup. I did some basic configuration and I can login fine via PAM, but it says "Spawn failed" after the login page.

Ideally I'd like to stick with just notebooks + LDAP auth if possible to make things simpler. If that is not possible, can anyone help me out with what type of configuration I need for hub to frontend notebooks and just forward to the existing setup I have?

- Hub is currently running on :8000
- Notebooks is currently running on :8888
- I also have custom themes on Notebooks that I want to keep, even if I have to use Hub.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Hub, I ended up just using Apache to front end the connection and then proxy to 127.0.0.1:8888 localhost.

This allowed me to utilize LDAP auth as well as the certificates that I'm already utilizing with Apache.